# Fast and reliable way to insert into SQL table from vb.net Datagridview which has more than thousand rows

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, datatable, insert

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to find a better solution than what I am doing now.

this is my vb.net insert command from the form which has dgvs with tables of 'dtOrders' and 'dtItems'. The issue I am facing now that sometimes all selected data doesn't insert into sql over internet dueto connection drop or slow connection. So what I want is send all data at once to sql and do the insert in sql stored procedure or something like that.

```vb
Sub Inserts() ' ScanPointLog, spSendToFactory
    Dim CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt")
    Try
        'Insert Into ScanPointLog
        MyCon.Open()
        Query = "Declare @tId int set @tId=(select count(TripId) from ScanPointLog where BranchCode='" & BranchCodee & "' and ScanPoint='" & ScanPointName & "')+1
                Insert into ScanPointLog(BranchCode, ScanPoint, TripId, DoneBy, DateTime, Driver, CarNo, ItemShouldBe, ActualTaken, MissedAny, MissedCount, TookExtra, ExtraCount, chkdSkipTrackItem, chkdSelectAllOrders,[Open]) 
                Values('" & BranchCodee & "','" & ScanPointName & "',@tId,'" & UserIdd & "','" & CurrentDate & "','" & cmbDrivers.SelectedValue & "','" & txtCarNo.Text & "','" & TotalItemShouldBeForSelectedOrders & "','" & TotalItemTackenInTheTrip & "','" & IsThereAnyMissing & "','" & missingItems & "', '" & IsThereExtras & "','" & takingExtras & "',@skipTrckItem, @chckdAllOrdrs,1 )"
        Command = New SqlCommand(Query, MyCon)
        Command.Parameters.Add("@skipTrckItem", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt16(chbByPassTrackItem.Checked)
        Command.Parameters.Add("@chckdAllOrdrs", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt16(chbSelectAllOrders.Checked)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MyCon.Close()

        'to get the saving tripid which was automatically took from above inser query
        MyCon.Open()
        Query = "Declare @tId int set @tId=(select count(TripId) from ScanPointLog where BranchCode='" & BranchCodee & "' and ScanPoint='" & ScanPointName & "')
                select @tId as Result"
        Command = New SqlCommand(Query, MyCon)
        dtreaderTripIdafterSave = Command.ExecuteReader
        While dtreaderTripIdafterSave.Read
            ThisTripID = dtreaderTripIdafterSave.Item(0)
        End While
        lblTripID.Text = ThisTripID
        MyCon.Close()


        'Insert Orders into table spSendToFactory
        MyCon.Open()
        For Each row As DataRow In dtOrders.Rows
            If row("Checked") = True Then
                Dim TrackItem As Integer
                If row("TrackItem") = "Yes" Then
                    TrackItem = 1
                Else
                    TrackItem = 0
                End If
                Query = "If not Exists (Select * from spSendToFactory where OrderNo = @nOrderNo and IsItem=0 and BranchCode=@nBranchcode )
                        begin
                        Insert into spSendToFactory(OrderNo, DateTime, IsItem, BranchCode, TrackItem,CameFrom_Page,CameFrom_Table,CameFrom_TripID) Values(@nOrderNo,@nDtTm,0,@nBranchcode,@trkItem,'" & PreviouseScanPoint_Form & "','" & PreviouseScanPoint_Table & "','" & ThisTripID & "')                      
                        end;
                        Update spOrdered set TripId= '" & ThisTripID & "',Done= 1 where OrderNo = @nOrderNo AND IsItem=0;   
                        Update Orders set OrderStatus= '" & ScanPointName & "' where OrderNo = @nOrderNo "
                Command = New SqlCommand(Query, MyCon)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nOrderNo", row("OrderNo").ToString)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nDtTm", CurrentDate)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nBranchcode", BranchCodee)
                Command.Parameters.Add("@trkItem", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = TrackItem
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next


        'Insert Items into table spSendToFactory
        For Each iRow As DataRow In dtItems.Rows
            If iRow("Checked") = True Then
                Query = "If not Exists (Select * from spSendToFactory where OrderNo = @nOrderNo and IsItem=1 and ItemBarcode=@nItemBcode and BranchCode=@nBranchcode )
                        begin
                        Insert into spSendToFactory(OrderNo, DateTime, IsItem, ItemBarcode, BranchCode,CameFrom_Page,CameFrom_Table,CameFrom_TripID ) Values(@nOrderNo,@nDtTm,1,@nItemBcode,@nBranchcode,'" & PreviouseScanPoint_Form & "','" & PreviouseScanPoint_Table & "','" & ThisTripID & "')
                        end;
                        Update spOrdered set TripId= '" & ThisTripID & "', Done= 1 where OrderNo = @nOrderNo AND IsItem=1 AND ItemBarcode= @nItemBcode ;
                        Update OrderItem set ItemStatus= '" & ScanPointName & "' where OrderNo = @nOrderNo AND ItemBarcode= @nItemBcode "
                Command = New SqlCommand(Query, MyCon)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nOrderNo", iRow("OrderNo").ToString)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nDtTm", CurrentDate)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nItemBcode", iRow("ItemBarcode").ToString)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nBranchcode", BranchCodee)
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next


        'Insert missing items into ScnPntMissItems
        For Each mRow As DataRow In dtMissedItems.Rows
            Query = "If not Exists 
                    (Select * from ScnPntMissItems where 
                    [BranchCode]='" & BranchCodee & "' and 
                    [ScanPoint]= '" & ScanPointName & "' and
                    [TripId] = '" & ThisTripID & "' and
                    [OrderNo]= @nOrderNo and
                    [ItemBarcode] = @nItemBcode)
                    begin
                    Insert into ScnPntMissItems([BranchCode],[ScanPoint],[TripId],[DateTime],[OrderNo],[ItemName],[ItemBarcode]) Values('" & BranchCodee & "','" & ScanPointName & "','" & ThisTripID & "','" & CurrentDate & "',@nOrderNo,@nItemName,@nItemBcode)
                    end"
            Command = New SqlCommand(Query, MyCon)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nOrderNo", mRow("OrderNo").ToString)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nItemName", mRow("ItemName").ToString)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nItemBcode", mRow("ItemBarcode").ToString)
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next


        'Insert extra items into ScnPntExtraItems
        For Each eRow As DataRow In dtExtarItems.Rows
            Query = "If not Exists 
                    (Select * from ScnPntExtraItems where 
                    [BranchCode]='" & BranchCodee & "' and 
                    [ScanPoint]= '" & ScanPointName & "' and
                    [TripId] = '" & ThisTripID & "' and
                    [OrderNo]= @nOrderNo and
                    [ItemBarcode] = @nItemBcode)
                    begin
                    Insert into ScnPntExtraItems([BranchCode],[ScanPoint],[TripId],[DateTime],[OrderNo],[ItemName],[ItemBarcode]) Values('" & BranchCodee & "','" & ScanPointName & "','" & ThisTripID & "','" & CurrentDate & "',@nOrderNo,@nItemName,@nItemBcode)
                    end;
                    Update spOrdered set TripId= '" & ThisTripID & "', Done= 1 where OrderNo = @nOrderNo AND IsItem=1 AND ItemBarcode= @nItemBcode ;
                    Update OrderItem set ItemStatus= '" & ScanPointName & "' where OrderNo = @nOrderNo AND ItemBarcode= @nItemBcode"
            Command = New SqlCommand(Query, MyCon)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nOrderNo", eRow("OrderNo").ToString)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nItemName", eRow("ItemName").ToString)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nItemBcode", eRow("ItemBarcode").ToString)
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next

        Query = "Update ScanPointLog set [Close]=1 where BranchCode='" & BranchCodee & "' and ScanPoint='" & ScanPointName & "' and TripId= '" & ThisTripID & "' "
        Command = New SqlCommand(Query, MyCon)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MyCon.Close()
        failed_to_upload = False
        MsgBox("Trip ID:  " & ThisTripID & "  at  '" & ScanPointName & "'  saved successfully")



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        failed_to_upload = True
        MsgBox("The uploading process could NOT be completed properly due to network issue.

The Trip ID '" & ThisTripID & "' of '" & ScanPointName & "' may not include checked orders or items correctly. Therefor please contact system administrator with following details to roll back this event immediately.

Trip ID     = '" & ThisTripID & "'
Scan Point  = '" & ScanPointName & "'")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You should look into the `SqlBulkCopy` class.  Populate a `DataTable` with the data first and then save with bulk copy.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney for the suggestion. I will search on that.

Comment: dear , it seems i can not check by running this query at every datarow 'If not Exists (Select * from spSendToFactory where OrderNo = @nOrderNo and IsItem=0 and BranchCode=@nBranchcode )'

Comment: Bulk copy is for straight inserts. It can be fast because it's very specific. If you need more flexibility then use the same `DataTable` but create a `SqlDataAdapter` and configure its `InsertCommand` appropriately and then call its `Update` method. You can use whatever SQL you like then.

Comment: You might like to check out [this example](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&p=3112830&viewfull=1#post3112830).